# Data not appearing in HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am trying to create something like this [resizable HighChart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/).
The difference is that i am loading my data from a blob.
This is the graph that i receive:
[image]

This is part of the received data, from the console.log(lines);:

> [{ date: '7/13/2016 8:35:00 AM', value: 60 },{ date: '7/13/2016
> 8:36:00 AM', value: 45 },...]

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/end5xc7m/

```
series: [{
  turboThreshold: 20000,
  type: 'area',
  name: 'Values to date',
  data: data}
```

I believe this is where i am getting the problem from, in the function visitorData.

I am not having the data projected onto the graph.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle that shows the actual problem? The current fiddle is not loading anything.

Comment: If the data you've posted in your question is the actual data you're trying to plot, it won't work as is. Look here to see how data should be formatted: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series | Also, dates must be sent as integer epoch time stamp in milliseconds (as returned by Date.UTC), not string format

Comment: It doesn't load because of the problem you and mike addressed. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **jlbriggs** noted, this is due to a formatting issue. Unless you you're using categories to plot your axes, Highcharts visualizations will not draw if data are input as strings.

I've updated your fiddle with a few fixes: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/end5xc7m/2/

```
function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r?\n/);
    var lines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length - 1; i++) {
        var currentLine = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        var thisLineValue = [Date.parse(currentLine[0]),parseInt(currentLine[1])];
        lines.push(thisLineValue);
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Here's what I changed:

- What you want to pass along to your chart is a set of arrays like `[x,y]`, where these variables are either dates or numbers. Building the values using curly braces and `+` concatenation operators turns these into strings. So, instead, I created a temporary array called `thisLineValue` and pushed that to your `lines` array.
- Next, within that temporary array, I used `Date.parse()` to turn your date values into timestamps. This is happily understood by Highcharts for `datetime` axes, as you set with your x-axis.
- For your y-axis value, I used `parseInt()` to avoid those values being turned into strings as well.
- Finally, I removed the `toString()` function when you return the `lines` array to the chart. Again, this keeps the values in the format the chart is expecting (dates and numbers).

I hope this is helpful for you!